# Why this.Grid.RestoreLayoutFromXml doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I create my own class, and inherit from TableView.

```
public class ABGridView : TableView
{
```

in this class I save current layout like this

```
string fileName = @"D:\aa.xml";
this.Grid.SaveLayoutToXml(fileName);
```

and it's work, but when I'm trying to restore layout it doesn't work.

```
private void ABGridView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      string fileName = @"D:\aa.xml";
      this.Grid.RestoreLayoutFromXml(fileName);
}
```

So I need your helps friends. I can't understand why it doesn't work...
Thanks ...

Comment: Your best bet is to ask DevExpress support, not here. In either case, you'll need to provide a lot more information. "Doesn't work" is not a helpful problem summary.

Comment: See this link https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7550

Comment: thanks, but RestoreLayoutFromXml is working in other projects, I think that the problem connected with inherit or something else

Answer (score 1):

When you save and restore a layout, it is necessary to specify the names of all objects that participate in layout saving. In this particular case, it is necessary to set the column names. 
For additional information about serialization in the GridControl, refer to the [Saving and Restoring Layouts](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6797) help article.

Comment: Thanks, Vikram you help me to find a problem, it's connect with Grid column name- columns don't have the 'Name' property set. Can I restore layout without name, or set names programmatically???